# 9 errors from react out of no where (mern stack)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I've been working with react using mern stack. Everything was fine until I used JSON.parse in a function when getting data out of the mongo database. I clicked save and I got 9 errors. I removed all the code, everything relating to it as if I never attempted it and I'm still getting these 9 errors shown below:

Any pointers?

I'll show the error, then the package.json file

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 4:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to: - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }' - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this: resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 15:17-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/destroy'

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 19:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to: - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }' - install 'browserify-zlib' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this: resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 18:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to: - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }' - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this: resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:12-31

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/etag'

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 25:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to: - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }' - install 'stream-http' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this: resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 31:18-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to: - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }' - install 'querystring-es3' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this: resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 3:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/mime'

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/send'

```
{
  "name": "micro-reactor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

^ that's the package.json file

I was advised to upload the package-lock.json file too but that's 30,000 lines of code. This is a reuploaded question as I couldn't edit my previous question for some reason after someone requested me to

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I had uploaded a import { json } from 'express/lib/response';
in one of the react files, that's what was causing all the errors